# C#: same command using command-line and c# code not working

Tags: c#, command-line, process

So i have `python` project inside this folder: `C:\root` and inside this `path` i have this file: `C:\root\\my_class.py`
And from `command-line`:

```
cd C:\root
```

And than run my code:

```
python my_class.py -p C:\Regression -a some_value -n HW
```

So from command line this works fine but now i want to run it from `c#` code and read the output:

**Change directory:**

```cs
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\root";
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.Start();
```

**Run my command**

```cs
    string pythonPath = @"C:\Python37\python.exe";
    string command = "C:\root\\my_class.py -p C:\\Regression -a some_value -n HW";

    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = pythonPath;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = command;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);
    process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);
    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    process.WaitForExit();
    Console.ReadLine();
```

So in this case when i start this command using `c#` i got this `error`:

> C:\Python37\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\root\my_class.py': [Errno
>   22] Invalid argument

Comment: You have a carriage return after `C:` in the second line of your "Run my command" code block, because you failed to escape a backslash. Also, I'm really not sure what your "Change directory" block is meant to be about. It runs `cmd.exe` in some particular directory but that says nothing about the current directory for *your* process nor for any other processes you launch later.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I did wonder if that was a typo because of the error message.

Comment: @PaulF - if it's "just" a typo in the question then we have code that the OP has never run and so they've no idea if it produces the same problem they're asking about, which makes it equally problematic either way.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Tested the above code & error message is _"C:\..\python.exe: can't open file 'C:'"_

Answer (score 1):

You've already specified the executable in this line `string pythonPath = "C:\Python37\python.exe";`

I guess that you don't need to use `python` again in your command. 
`string command = "python C:\root\\my_class.py -p C:\\Regression -a some_value -n HW";`

Also you've mixed the slashes in a command, try having your command string as:

```cs
string command = "C:\\root\\my_class.py -p C:\\Regression -a some_value -n HW";
```

or

```cs
string command = @"C:\root\my_class.py -p C:\Regression -a some_value -n HW";
```

Comment: I cannot see the different here between your code and my (i probably missing something)

Comment: Don't use `python` twice and all slashes must be escaped or string must be @-quoted. In your code slash in `C:\root` isn't escaped